# Which MVC versions benefit from removing unused view engines?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

There are a few questions and answers on SO that talk about removing unused view engines to increase performance. For example, when you only use the Razor engine, you can remove the WebForm engine.

According to a [blog post from February 2011](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/02/07/mvc-performance-tips.aspx) by a (then) developer of the framework:

> **When:** Your application is using built-in display/editor templates (via the Html.EditorFor or Html.DisplayFor methods) and you are using only one type of view engine.
>
> **Why:** ASP.NET MVC is generally very good about caching file lookup hits (views, partials, display/editor templates). However one scenario that is not cached is the use of the built-in (default) display/editor templates (where all file lookups are misses).

Is this still true today? Which versions benefit from this?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, it's still true.  Not much has changed in MVC as far as the basic backend goes since 2011.